# How can I update json returned by terraform created policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a policy returned by one of terraform resources:

```
data.aws_iam_policy_document.cluster_assume_role_policy.json
```

the json object as follows:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::12345678900000:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/id/879BUOGVDDFGHFGVB85HJNVIFDHPJKPMC"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "oidc.eks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/id/879BUOGVDDFGHFGVB85HJNVIFDHPJKPMC:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to replace a couple of substrings within this json and be able to use it as a reference in another terraform resource, like a variable etc

1. replace sts.amazonaws.com with system:serviceaccount:kube-system:cluster-autoscaler
2. replace :aud with :sub

can you please suggest any/optimal way to achieve this via terraform tools/functions?

Comment: Why you cannot create a new one policy?

Comment: As already pointed out. The best way is to simply create new policy from scratch.

Comment: 1. we have 5 clusters, do want to re-use the existing policies on the fly
2. there is a general interest as well - what is the way to approach update of json data in Terraform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would agree with the comments this is best to do with a new policy from scratch ...
But we still can do it using the functions that terraform provides:
( jsondecode, jsonencode & replace )

Here is an example:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "test" {
  statement {
    sid     = ""
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"]

    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "s3:prefix"
      values   = ["sts.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}


output "replace" {
  value = jsondecode(
    replace(
      jsonencode(data.aws_iam_policy_document.test.json),
      "sts.amazonaws.com",
      "system:serviceaccount"
    )
  )
}
```

so there are a few functions there...

- with `jsonencode` we get a string out ot the policy json
- with `replace` we do the required replacement, you can call multiple times for your desired replacements.
- with `jsondecode` we convert the string back to a json so it can be consumed where needed